# Store records for a table in wordpress

Tags: php

I need to create a page in wordpress that displays a table with 3/4 fields, and let editors add and update the records in this table.

I'm a drupal developer and don't have much experience with wordpress. I know that in drupal I would just create a content type 'record' and than create a view to display a list. I can't think of any way to achieve that in wordpress (in a user friendly way. apperenetly my suggestion to have an unpublished post for each record with a tag 'record' isn't acceptable on my employers...)

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the WP-Table-Reloaded Plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-table-reloaded/

Screenshots are on the plugin author's website:

http://tobias.baethge.com/wordpress-plugins/wp-table-reloaded-english/

Comment: **Attention: [WP-Table Reloaded](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-table-reloaded/) has been replaced with TablePress!**
Please do not install WP-Table Reloaded anymore! Instead, please use the [TablePress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tablepress/) plugin, which is the official successor of WP-Table Reloaded. For users of WP-Table Reloaded, it is recommended to [migrate](http://tablepress.org/migration-from-wp-table-reloaded/) to TablePress. *Visit [TablePress' official website](http://tablepress.org/) for more information.*